# Create Purchase order using API in MyOB account using c#

Tags: myob

I want to create PO using c# Api in My-ob account.anybody have suggestion please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the instructions at [developer.myob.com](http://developer.myob.com/)?

Comment: Yes following but cant find appropriate when i am stuck.

Comment: and even cant find any video and sample for calling api sample(demo) for postman as xero provide.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the MYOB.AccountRight.SDK.Services.Purchase.ServiceBillService to create PO.